# Programming a Magnetic card reader to read employee number

Tags: windows, magnetic-cards

I am trying to program a Magnetic card reader and I do not know where to start. I have done research but there does not seem to be much out there.

1. Can I connect the card reader to the computer and program it through a IDE like eclipse?
2. What language would it be in?
3. How can I see the device on Windows 7 like a Thumb Drive, if possible?

I have the format I want the text to be in. I just do not understand the process of the readers programming.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You need to provide much much much more information.  Type of Card Reader, Model Number, Make, API interface, Start at the companies website.

Comment: Windows doesn't have a set of APIs for magnetic card devices, so tose devices would have to provide their own set of APIs. Each brand would likely have different implementations of APIs. Thus, you'll need to choose the device first, in order to learn its API.